# Google cloud-Internal Load balancer connectivity issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, internal-load-balancer, google-cloud-network-load-balancer

I have created 2 VMs (Webserver) in GCP on one region & TCP internal load balancer configured in the same region and created another vm on another region(southeast asia). Now, I am not able to ping load balancer IP but I am able to ping the webserver IP.

Webserver1---region :us-central ----10.128.0.5 &
Webserver2---region: us-central------10.128.0.6 &
Internal load balancer ip----------10.128.0.13

Test machine---region: southeast asia----10.148.0.5

Answer (score 0):

I understand that  by "pinging the load balancer " you mean you want to check the  healt of the load balancer.However pinging a load balancer is not possible  as it is a virtual part of a network and it is not a seperate  device.however u can check the  health of the  load balancer using  the instrucctions from the following docs.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/setting-up-internal

hope  that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

GCP internal load balancer by design handles traffic within the same region. As your test machine is in a different region(Southeast-asia), you cannot ping the internal load balancer which is present in the US-CENTRAL1 region.

Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing distributes HTTP and HTTPS traffic to backends hosted on Compute Engine and Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE). The load balancer is accessible only in the chosen region of your Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) network on an internal IP address.

Kindly refer to the below link for:

Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing overview :
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal

Troubleshooting Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/troubleshooting-ilb